# Display the commit history of a different branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I want to see the commits of a particular branch without checking out to that branch and issue `git log`. Is that possible at all? I searched for a while but I found nothing!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run `git log <branch>`.

For instance, if you want to see the log for the `master` branch, run:

```
git log master
```

At least, this works for me (I'm using git 1.9.2).

Answer (score 0):

`git log --branches=*<your-branchname>` as stated in the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

#### Options>Commit Limiting

`--branches[=<pattern>]`

Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on the command line as `<commit>`. If `<pattern>` is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks `?`, `*`, or `[`, `/*` at the end is implied.